# Value of $\pi$ by Aryabhata

Tags: math-history, pi

Aryabhata gave accurate approximate value of $\pi$.

He wrote in *Aryabhatiya* following:

**add 4 to 100, multiply by 8 and then add 62,000. The result is approximately the circumference of circle of diameter twenty thousand.**

By this rule the relation of the circumference to diameter is given.

This gives $\pi= \frac{62832}{20000}=3.1416$ which is approximately 3.14159265...(correct value of $\pi$)

---

From where did Aryabhata got all the above values(4, 100, 8, 62000)?

Comment: You mean $\dfrac{62832}{20000}$.

Comment: @TonyK I mean all the values in bold.

Comment: It could have been decimal rounding of Zu Chongzhi's earlier approximation of $\frac{355}{113}\approx 3.1415929\ldots$

Comment: Look again, Freddy! You have a misprint.

Comment: @TonyK ah there, I have edited it

Answer (score 2):

I am not a specialist in that history, but it seems unlikely that this formula be related to a computational algorithm he used. The constants $100$ and $62000$ do no remind anything that appears in the early computations of Pi. (At the time, inscribed polygons was the main approach.)

It really looks like this is a mnemonic way to express the figures, noting that $32$ is a multiple of $8$.

Using a diameter of $20000$ rather than $10000$ is another mystery, as it doesn't bring any simplification. Maybe Aryabhata needed $2\pi$ more frequently than $\pi$.

This is pure speculation from me.

Comment: Most people need $2\pi$ more often

Comment: @Henry: "Most people need $2\pi$ more often": maybe nowadays. In Aryabhata's time, I imagine that the main usages were circumference ($2\pi$) and area ($\pi$ or $\pi//4$) of the circle. I don't believe that surface ($4\pi$ or $\pi$) and volume ($\pi/6$ or $4\pi/3$) of the sphere could have had an impact. Radians weren't known...

Answer (score 0):

[Kim Plofker](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691120676) says that it probably was by computing the circumference of an inscribed polygon with 384 sides. She gives [Sarasvati Amma](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/8120813448) as a source; I have also seen a reference to [Florian Cajori](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821821024) with the same claim.

Comment: Archimedes' method with $384$ sides gives the bracketing $3.14155761<\pi<3.14166275$. This is compatible with the rounding $3.1416$ for the inscribed length.